# Implicit Type Conversion: If one operand is short & the other is char, will char be converted to short?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, short

K&R states, that if either operand is an `int` the other operand will be converted to `int`. Of course, that is only after all the other rules (like `long double`, `float`, `unsigned int` etc.) have been followed.

By that logic, `char` would be converted to `int`, if the other operand was an `int`. But what if the highest integer type in an operation is a `short`?

Now, obviously I don't need to explicitly convert a `char` to a bigger integer, but I do wonder, does ANSI-C handle implicit conversion between `char` and `short` under the hood? K&R does not say anything about that.

Say, I have the following lines of code:

```
char x = 'x';
short y = 42;
short z = x + y;
```

Will `x` be converted to `short`? Or will there be no conversion to begin with at all?

Just to make it clear: I'm not asking for whether or how to convert from `char` to `short`. I just want to know what happens in regards to implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "integer promotion" will convert both of them to `int` before the addition:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
> be used:
>
> — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
> than the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> [...]
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer
> promotions.

(ISO/IEC ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E), §6.3.1.1)

Comment: Interesting. Then that would also mean, when some arithmetic operation is done between two `short`s and the result would then be assigned to another `short`, the operands would be converted to `int` for calculation before converted back to `short` when assigning to a `short` variable?

Comment: Note that this also means that it is possible on some systems for the promotion to result in `unsigned int`, if `char` is unsigned (allowed, but rare) and has the same range as unsigned int (allowed, but rare).

Comment: @Miroslav Cetojevic: Yes, it means exactly that. But then, we are talking about the theoretical behaviour ("abstract machine") only. The implementation/compiler is free to drop such conversions if they have no impact.

Comment: @Miroslav Cetojevic: That is correct.  However, compilers can remove the conversions during optimization as long as the result is the same (and sometimes when it isn't, if there would be overflow).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: How could that occur?  I'm pretty certain that `int` is required to be capable of holding all values of `char`, is it not?

Comment: @supercat: Surprisingly, this is not guaranteed.  The `signed int` / `int` type (same thing) is guaranteed to hold all of the values representable by a `signed char`.  However, unlike `int` / `signed int`, the `char` type may not be the same type as `signed char`, instead it may be `unsigned char`.  If `char` and `int` are the same size (say, both 32 bits), then `int` cannot hold all of the values representable by `char`.   I believe there is a DSP architecture from TI which is not capable of loading anything smaller than a word, and on this architecture the C compiler has `sizeof(int) == 1`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I've used the TI compiler where `unsigned char` won't fit into `int`, but I thought that on such implementations `char` was required to be signed.

Comment: @supercat: There are no such requirements, but `char` is usually signed anyways.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: How would a function like `fgetc()` work if there existed `char` values that couldn't fit in `int`?  To be sure, using `fgetc()` on a system where `char` and `int` are the same would be somewhat more work than on one where `int` is larger, since a return value of `EOF` could represent an end-of-file condition but could also simply represent a character whose code matched the numerical value of `EOF`. I guess in cases where `int` can represent as many values as `char`, it would be possible to say that `fgetc()` will return an `int` which, when cast to `char`, will...

Comment: ...yield the character that was written, but I would think if the standard authors intended implementations to behave that way, they would have said something to that effect.

Answer (score -2):

According to the standard , `short` can never be defined using less number of bits than `char`. Therefore, `x` will indeed be converted to `short`.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Both will be converted to `int`, except on perhaps very bizarre systems where they may be converted to `unsigned int`.